# Python Bokeh: Selection-Bar for History in Interactive Data-Science visualisation?

Tags: python, selection, bokeh, data-science

Python Bokeh [here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/color_scatter.html) has very nice selection features

[image]

but I cannot find Selection-Bar for history like [Qlik](https://webapps.qlik.com/masters/index.html#/2018-stats/) with cancelling selection by the `X`:

[image]

### **Does Python's Bokeh have Selection-Bar for History or extension to get Selection-Bar for History?**

---

*Potentially interesting to readers*

> I haven't yet found the history selection bar in any data science tool:
>
> 1. R's [metricsgraphics](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-plot-with-metricsgraphics/) and Shiny seems to be lacking Selection History bar.
> 2. Python's Shiny-alternatives [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-something-similar-to-R-Shiny-for-Python-users-in-the-scientific-community), such as Bookeh and Spyro, seems to be missing the Selection History bar.

Answer (score 1):

As of version `0.12.15`, Bokeh does have a built-in one. Users have managed various workaround solutions using things like custom extensions, or UI event callbacks. However, a fairly detailed plan to add this feature to the core library was recently outlined in this issue:

[`#7795` **Feature-request: Selection-Bar**](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7795)

I am hopeful that this will be added and available in the next few releases.